# ReactJS Axios Call API Failed: Network Error on Safari

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm working on a login function via an API call. On Chrome it works fine with click 1 time to login but somehow on Safari It caused issues sometimes, I have to click a few times. It also gave an error as the pic below. Please help if you can, many thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A protocol error could be caused when you use https instead of http.

Try changing your baseURL from `https://...` to `http://...` and see if it works.

Comment: Can you provide more context to your problem. Like the code block producing the error.